# Append returned api data to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, leaflet, popup

I am trying to return some information from a public holidays API and display it on a leaflet map, within a table, on a pop up.

The pop up is working and the data is showing up correctly in the console but not in the pop up itself. My code isn't having the desired effect of adding new rows to the table with the date and name of each public holiday (this info changes dependent on which country the map is showing).

Any advice/anything I'm missing?

Section relating to this:

```
success: function(result) {
    
                console.log(result);
            
                if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                    
                    var countryHolidays = [];
        
                    $.each(result.data, function(index, value){
                        
                        if (value.location){
                            var newLocation = value.location.join();
                            countryHolidays.push({ name: value.country, date: value.date, location: newLocation});
                        } else {
                            countryHolidays.push({ name: value.country, date: value.date, location: "Nationwide"});
                        }
                        
                    });
                    
                        var info =
                        `
                        <div id="holidays-div" class="bg-success mx-0 my-0 px-1 py-1">
                        <table id="holidays-table" class="table table-striped table-responsive border-0 rounded-12px mx-0 my-0 px-0 py-0">
                        <thead class="bg-success text-white">
                            <th colspan="2">Public Holidays</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>Name</td><td>Date</td></tr>
                            
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        `
                        
                        countryHolidays.forEach((element) => {
                            
                            $('#holidays-table tr:last').append("<tr><td>" + element.name + "</td><td>" + element.date + "</td></tr>");
                    
                        });

                        holidayMarker.addLayer(L.marker([$('#lat').text(), $('#lng').text()], {icon: holidayicon}).bindPopup(info));
                                    };
                                        
                        mymap.addLayer(holidayMarker);  
                        

            }, ...
```

Comment: Your table is still not added inside dom and you are using `$('#holidays-table tr:last')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're refering on an element that is not even generated yet. Try to make the table first.

> $('#holidays-table tr:last').append("" + element.name + "" + element.date + "");

In the section above says that you want to append something to the holidays table but in the meantime that table doesn't even exist (you store the element in a variable called info). So first, add this inside DOM (like append this to the body) and after that, make operations with it. Here is an example

```
$("body").append(info)
$('#holidays-table tr:last').append(...
```

And after this, you can append anything you want (like the content inside your loop). I hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks for your help - This is working for me to add a table at the bottom of the body of the page but I need the table to be inside the pop up

Comment: It's just an example. Replace the target of the append tag. The point is that you have to generate the **info** first before you do anything with it.  1. Create/Append the popup. 2. Create/Append the table to the popup. 3. Create/Append rows into the table. The order is important! According to your code, you created rows to the table whic isn't appended yet so basically you want to add it to something that doesn't even exist.